# How did Anakin Skywalker defeat Darth SIdious?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Today I saw [Darth Sidious fighting Darth Maul and Savage Opress](https://youtu.be/-7hBZNsPnyg?t=1m58s). It's pretty clear that Darth Sidious is hypercompetent at fighting, both with lightsabers and with the Force.

Comparing that to [the famous scene in which Skywalker kills Sidious](https://youtu.be/lbbG02LB7g0), Sidious looks like he's just sitting there and letting Skywalker pick him up and dump him in a hole. So why is he so passive once lifted by Skywalker? and furthermore, why doesn't he predict Vader's attack on him (like Snoke did with Ren in Episode V*)?

---

*Of course, Snoke doesn't do this so well, but you'd expect Sidious, being incredibly strong in the Dark Side as well as paranoid (he didn't sleep for fear of something happening while he was incapacitated, according to Wookieepedia), to at least be forewarned that something *might* be amiss with his apprentice.

Comment: Relevant; [Why didn't the Emperor realize that torturing Luke to death in front of Vader might be a bad idea?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85726/why-didnt-the-emperor-realize-that-torturing-luke-to-death-in-front-of-vader-mi)

Comment: Second part of the question is answered here; [Why did Emperor fail to foresee his own death by Vader?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/why-did-emperor-fail-to-foresee-his-own-death-by-vader?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Ugh, I was so sure that this question hadn't been answered before! Ah well. At least I get the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ren is in _The Empire Strikes Back_  (aka Episode V)? I sure don't recall that. Of course, the last time I saw it was 1997...